# Getting each word of a line which is separated by tabs

Tags: javascript, string, split

```js
let line = '1    test    test@gmail.com';

let column = line.split('\t');

console.log(column[0] + '-' + column[1] + '-' + column[2]);
```

output I'm getting back:

```
1    test    test@gmail.com-undefined-undefined
```

Expected output:

```
1-test-test@gmail.com
```

How can we achieve this?

Comment: try `let line = '1\ttest\ttest@gmail.com';` if you want to split by tab

Comment: your example seems to use 4 spaces for representing tabs rather than a `\t`

Comment: There is no tab in the `line` string. It just spaces.

Comment: Tabs are an [actual character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0009/index.htm) not just a bunch of spaces.  If you want to match a bunch of spaces, try a regular expression `\s+`

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace or split - I would trim the line first to be sure

Note, your line did not contain tabs. The `\s+` is any number of [whitespace characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes):

> **\s** Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed, and other Unicode spaces. Equivalent to [ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff].

```js
let line = '    1    test    test@gmail.com   ';

let columns = line.trim().split(/\s+/) // .join("-")
console.log(columns); // in case you need them in an array
let combined = columns.join("-");

console.log(combined);
```

Comment: One tiny nitpick.  The OP used `column` to represent the array of split columns, and you used `column` to represent the combined result.  I like that you used the plural `columns` for the array, but maybe `column` is not the best name for the joined version.  Maybe just `result` or something (OP logged it directly without a name).

Answer (score 1):

No need to split and join (you could have used `column.join('-')` for that), simply replace by using a regex. `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters. You can also use `\t` if that's enough in your case. `/g` makes sure it replaces all occurences instead of only one.

```js
let line = '1    test    test@gmail.com';

let column = line.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

console.log(column);
```